# Why isn't it possible to paste through the context menu in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

On a Google Sheets, when I right click, I get the context menu:

[image: context menu]

"Paste Special" works as expected but when I select "Paste", I get this:

[image: shortcut keys help menu]

and I don't understand why this isn't allowed.

Comment: Only Google can answer why. Anyway this limitation doesn't happen on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

As November 28, 2017, this is a browser dependent feature. On Chrome Copy/Paste contextual and dropdown menus work as expected but in other browsers they don't. The alternative is to use keyboard shortcuts.

Reference

- [Copy and paste text and images](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/161768?hl=en)

Comment: I would understand the security reason when getting the OS' clipboard, but since we're talking about a context menu where they manage an internal clipboard (they handle 'paste special'), I still fail to see the reasoning behind it, unless it's about 'use chrome'.